# Creating a new directive with AngularJS using HTML5 audio element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, audio

I am new with angular and I've made audio buttons using angular directive:

```
app.directive('soundButton', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var audioSrc = attrs.origem;
            var audio = new Audio(audioSrc);

            scope.play = function () {
                if (audio.paused) {
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                }
            };

            element.css({
                borderRadius: '50%',
                width: '100px',
                height: '100px', 
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                display: 'inline-block'
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

...and put the html code on my page:

```
<section id="bla" data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <sound-button data-ng-click="play()" origem="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/sys100%20drumkit/24[kb]909-klick.aif.mp3" class="col-md-4"></sound-button>
            <sound-button data-ng-click="play()" origem="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/sys100%20drumkit/2[kb]hihat_closed.aif.mp3" class="col-md-4"></sound-button>
            <sound-button data-ng-click="play()" origem="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/sys100%20drumkit/34[kb]noicybell.aif.mp3" class="col-md-4"></sound-button>
        </section>
```

But always I click the audio button, it plays the same sound. (I suspect this could be an array of elements issue)

**FIDDLERJS**: http://jsfiddle.net/qumjmz9y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio element has source element. So you must change this element. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: But in this case when I instantiate the new Audio object, I'm already setting the source: var audio = new Audio(source); Or not?

Comment: fiddle => [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qumjmz9y/2/) 
your mistake is reaching audio element directly. 
`scope.play = function () {
                if (audio.paused) {
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                }
            };`
The audio element in the link function pointers the latest audio source. So you must find that audio **in some way** and call play pause function. I used _$event_ as parameter for your play function call.

Answer (score 0):

**YOU Should define inner SOURCE tag**

```
app.directive('soundButton', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var audioSrc = attrs.origem,
                audio = angular.element('<audio/>'),
                inner = angular.element('<source/>');

            inner.attr('src', audioSrc);
            audio.attr('autoplay', true);
            audio.attr('control', false);
            //audio.attr('loop', true);
            element.append(audio);
            audio.append(inner);

            scope.play = function () {

                if (audio[0].paused) {
                    audio[0].play();
                } else {
                    audio[0].pause();
                }
            };

            element.css({
                borderRadius: '50%',
                width: '100px',
                height: '100px', 
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                display: 'inline-block'
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```